# Laravel updating wrong modals

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Laravel is updating the wrong rows `$winner_number is = 0` but it's updating `selectedItem` "green." I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

```
// Laravel is updating wrong rows
$number_games = Game::where('period', $period)
    ->where('selectedItem', $winner_number)
    ->where('game_type_id', $game_type_id)->get();

// $number_games is empty but still its updating different modals 
foreach ($number_games as $number_game) {
    $number_game->received_amount = $number_game->bet_amount *
        $parameter->win_number_times;
    $number_game->status = "success";
    $number_game->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think forgot to put double-quotes. You are searching for a string here

```
$number_games = Game::where('period', $period)
    ->where('selectedItem', "$winner_number")
    ->where('game_type_id', "$game_type_id")->get();

foreach ($number_games as $number_game) {
    $number_game->received_amount = $number_game->bet_amount * $parameter->win_number_times;
    $number_game->status = "success";
    $number_game->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve without loop

```
$number_games = Game::where('period', $period)->where('selectedItem',
        $winner_number)
        ->where('game_type_id', $game_type_id)->update([
            'status'=>'success',
            'received_amount'=>DB::raw(vsprintf('bet_amount* %s',[$parameter->win_number_times]))
        ])
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'violet' (SQL: update `games` set `status` = success, `games`.`updated_at` = 2021-07-04 22:18:56 where `period` = 20210704438 and `selectedItem` = 0 and `game_type_id` = 1)

Comment: @Ganeshrao can you show Game model and database tble structure

Comment: my model <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Game extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function game_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(GameType::class);
    }

    public function transaction(){
      return $this->hasOne(Transaction::class);
    }
}

Comment: Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('period');
            $table->string('selectedItem');
            $table->string('total_amount');
            $table->string('bet_amount');
            $table->string('service_charge');
            $table->string('received_amount')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->default('waiting');

Comment: $table->unsignedBigInteger('game_type_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('game_type_id')->references('id')->on('game_types')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); 
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: @Ganeshrao try once by commenting where('period', $period . if it works then pass proper string isntea of datetime

Comment: also what value you have in $parameter->win_number_times